# how to correctly use Google Protobuf, when using imports in Javascript

Tags: javascript, protocol-buffers

Lets suppose there are two .proto files, file hello.proto and file core.proto.

File core.proto is imported with import statement like

`import "core.proto";`

content of files:

hello.proto

```
syntax = "proto3";

import "core.proto";

message GetBalance {
    string address = 1;
}
```

core.proto

```
syntax = "proto3";

message Block {
    string chain = 1;
}
```

I run protoc with

`protoc --proto_path=./ --js_out=import_style=commonjs,binary:./ *.proto`

Javascript files are generated, but because of "import" statement there is something like

`goog.object.extend(proto, core_pb);`

and thats a problem because when I try to import this javascript file into my code,

`import * as hello_pb from './hello_pb'`

it does not work, it says "proto is not defined" it is a reference error.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you include the full code (or better, the minimum example that shows your problem) of files A and B?

Comment: @herchu i've edited the example and added complete files

Comment: Can you show the generated file, please?

Comment: Why use `commonjs` for `import_style` if you use ES6 modules?

Answer (score 0):

While this answer will not directly solve your import problem, it may give you a workaround.

An alternative to "compiling" protobuf into JS is to use [protobufjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/protobufjs) which implements protobuf and can handle loading arbitrary `.proto` files. It has its disadvantages (not as lightweight as your solution could be) but it works well.

Assuming you distribute your `.proto` in your environment (service, app, whatever it is) importing `protobufjs` and deserializing a message would be something like:

```js
import { loadSync } from 'protobufjs';
...
const protoRoot = loadSync('path/to/hello.proto'));
const Hello = protoRoot.lookupType('Hello'); // can be some_namespace.Hello
...
let message = Hello.decode(buffer);
```

Most (if not all) datatypes and encoding/decoding is supported. Check out [protobuf project page](https://protobufjs.github.io/protobuf.js/).